# How can I get current time stamp and it's operations in WSO2 BPS Server 3.1.0

Tags: bpel, wso2, apache-ode, wso2-esb

I am working on the WSO2 BPS Server 3.1.0, How can I get the current timestamp and

How can I  perform the subtract   operations on these Time Stamp.

I Tried like this:-

```
get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')
```

It's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [`current-dateTime()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-current-dateTime) with XPath 2.0?

Comment: But, i am using XPath 1.0

Comment: Why not changing it only for a certain expression to XPath 2.0? If you use ODE, it supports both out of the box.

Comment: Hi Vanto,i am getting the **Unknown function "current-dateTime" used in <bpel:from>** error && my code is **https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8662971**

Comment: Hi Vanto,Is there any deadline or Escalation expression available in   Apache ODE(BPEL).